# How can I create Javascript object on the fly in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through an array `response` and I want to put some values from it into an object `data` but my method below doesn't work ("data[i] is not defined").

```
var data = {},
    i = 0;

$(response).each(function(){
    data[i].title = response.title; // This does not work
    data[i].id = response.id;
    i++;
}
```

**I want the resulting object `data` to look like this:**

```
{
    0: {
          title: "First title",
          id: "First id"
       },

    1: {
          title: "Second title",
          id: "Second id"
       },
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the documentation for [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: You need to learn more about the difference between arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var data = {},
    i = 0;

$(response).each(function(){
    data[i] = {}; // Initialize an object first before assigning values: data[i] = {};.
    data[i].title = this.title; //Use this instead of response
    data[i].id = this.id;
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but why use this instead of response? Any differences in the outcome?

Comment: @Weblurk: `this` is current item in the loop while `response` is your array

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing each index of the response, you are referencing properties off the array/object

```
$(response).each(function(index){
    data[i].title = response[index].title; 
    data[i].id = response[index].id;
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var data = [];

$(response).each(function(index, element){
    data.push({
        title: element.title,
        id:    element.id
    });
}
```

This snippet will create an array with object in it, so you can access them with:

```
data[0]; // [1], [2] ...
```

Comment: Probably because the structure is not consistent with what the OP asked. Equally `response.title` doesn't refer to the item in each iteration of the `.each()` loop